# Is the sequence $v _ { n + 1 } = \frac { 2 v _ { n } + 3} { v _ { n } + 4 }$ decreasing and converging to 1?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$(v_n)$ is a sequence defined by
$$v_1= 2 , \text { and } v _ { n + 1 } = \frac { 2 v _ { n } + 3} { v _ { n } + 4 }$$
We know that $v _ { n } \geq 1 , \forall n \in N$
I saw that this sequence is decreasing and converges to 1 right or wrong ?

Comment: The limit cannot be $1$, you are having some issue in your answer then. The sequence is decreasing, though.

Comment: Draw the function $y=\frac{2x+5}{x+4}$ and solve the equality  $x=\frac{2x+5}{x+4}$.Hope it helps .

Comment: Please read the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). If you don't know how the site works, it's going to be hard for you to earn reputation.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just a note that it may be helpful in future to add a more specific title to your question, try to ensure that the title conveys what the question is about. The answer to the question in your title "is it right or wrong?" is "yes" but this isn't very helpful for either you in answering your actual question, or the person reading the title.

Answer (score 2):

It is decreasing and $\geq 1$ but the limit is not $1$. The limit $l$ satisfies the equation $l(l+4)=2l+5$. Thus $l^{2}+2l-5=0$. The roots are $l=\frac {-2\pm \sqrt {4+20}} 2$ and the positive root is $l=\frac {-2+\sqrt {4+20}} 2$. This is the limit of the sequence.

EDIT:  for the revised question your answer is correct since the only positive solution of $l^{2}+2l-3=0$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

as a hint, try to rearrange
\begin{align}
\frac{2v_n + 3}{v_n + 4} &= \frac{v_n-1+v_n+4}{v_n+4}\\
&= \frac{v_n+4}{v_n+4}+\frac{v_n-1}{v_n+4} \\
&= 1 + \frac{v_n-1}{v_n+4}
\end{align}
Now, for asymptotic reasons, investigate the graph
$$y=1 + \frac{x-1}{x+4}$$

Comment: Oh now I change

Comment: You really shouldn't change the question after an answer is posed, a lot of what follows underneath is based on the original post. However I will edit to reflect this change